# Perl 6 and `multi method new`

Tags: polymorphism, raku

I have a class `Price` that encapsulates an `Int`. I also would like it to have constructors for `Num` and `Str`. I thought I could do this by making `Price::new` a multi method with various type constraints, but this isn't the behavior I expected. It looks like `Price.new` is skipping the constructor altogether and going straight to `BUILD`, bypassing the casting logic.

I know from looking at other Perl 6 code that using `multi method new` is acceptable. However, I haven't been able to find an example of a polymorphic constructor with different type constraints. How do I rewrite this code to force it to use the casting logic in the constructor?

**lib/Price.pm6**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6 -w

use v6;

unit class Price:ver<0.0.1>;

class X::Price::PriceInvalid is Exception {
    has $.price;

    method message() {
        return "Price $!price not valid"
    }
}

# Price is stored in cents USD
has $.price;

multi method new(Int $price) {
    say "Int constructor";
    return self.bless(:$price);
}

multi method new(Num $price) {
    say "Num constructor";
    return self.new(Int($price * 100));
}

multi method new(Str $price) {
    say "String constructor";
    $price .= trans(/<-[0..9.]>/ => '');
    unless ($price ~~ m/\.\d**2$/) {
        die(X::Price::PriceInvalid(:$price));
    }
    return self.new(Num($price));
}

submethod BUILD(:$!price) { say "Low-level BUILD constructor" }

method toString() {
    return sprintf("%.2f", ($!price/100));
}
```

**t/price.t**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl6 -w

use v6;
use Test;

use-ok 'Price', 'Module loads';
use Price;

# test constructor with Int
my Int $priceInt = 12345;
my $priceIntObj = Price.new(price => $priceInt);
is $priceIntObj.toString(), '123.45',
    'Price from Int serializes correctly';

# test constructor with Num
my $priceNum = Num.new(123.45);
my $priceNumObj = Price.new(price => $priceNum);
is $priceNumObj.toString(), '123.45',
    'Price from Num serializes correctly';

# test constructor with Num (w/ extra precision)
my $priceNumExtra = 123.4567890;
my $priceNumExtraObj = Price.new(price => $priceNumExtra);
is $priceNumExtraObj.toString(), '123.45',
    'Price from Num with extra precision serializes correctly';

# test constructor with Str
my $priceStr = '$123.4567890';
my $priceStrObj = Price.new(price => $priceStr);
is $priceStrObj.toString(), '123.45',
    'Price from Str serializes correctly';

# test constructor with invalid Str that doesn't parse
my $priceStrInvalid = 'monkey';
throws-like { my $priceStrInvalidObj = Price.new(price => $priceStrInvalid) }, X::Price::PriceInvalid,
    'Invalid string does not parse';

done-testing;
```

**Output of `PERL6LIB=lib/ perl6 t/price.t`**

```
ok 1 - Module loads
Low-level BUILD constructor
ok 2 - Price from Int serializes correctly
Low-level BUILD constructor
not ok 3 - Price from Num serializes correctly
# Failed test 'Price from Num serializes correctly'
# at t/price.t line 18
# expected: '123.45'
#      got: '1.23'
Low-level BUILD constructor
not ok 4 - Price from Num with extra precision serializes correctly
# Failed test 'Price from Num with extra precision serializes correctly'
# at t/price.t line 24
# expected: '123.45'
#      got: '1.23'
Low-level BUILD constructor
Cannot convert string to number: base-10 number must begin with valid digits or '.' in '⏏\$123.4567890' (indicated by ⏏)
  in method toString at lib/Price.pm6 (Price) line 39
  in block <unit> at t/price.t line 30
```

Comment: I think you might want to multiply the input by `100` always.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of the `new` multi methods that you wrote take one positional argument.

```perl6
:( Int $ )
:( Num $ )
:( Str $ )
```

You are calling new with a named argument though

```perl6
:( :price($) )
```

The problem is that since you didn't write one that would accept that, it uses the default `new` that `Mu` provides.

---

If you don't want to allow the built-in `new`, you could write a `proto` method to prevent it from searching up the inheritance chain.

```perl6
proto method new (|) {*}
```

If you want you could also use it to ensure that all potential sub-classes also follow the rule about having exactly one positional parameter.

```perl6
proto method new ($) {*}
```

---

If you want to use named parameters, use them.

```perl6
multi method new (Int :$price!){…}
```

---

You might want to leave `new` alone and use multi submethod `BUILD` instead.

```perl6
multi submethod BUILD (Int :$!price!) {
    say "Int constructor";
}

multi submethod BUILD (Num :$price!) {
    say "Num constructor";
    $!price = Int($price * 100); 
}

multi submethod BUILD (Str :$price!) {
    say "String constructor";
    $price .= trans(/<-[0..9.]>/ => '');
    unless ($price ~~ m/\.\d**2$/) {
        die(X::Price::PriceInvalid(:$price));
    }
    $!price = Int($price * 100);
}
```

---

Actually I would always multiply the input by `100`, so that `1` would be the same as `"1"` and `1/1` and `1e0`.
I would also divide the output by 100 to get a Rat.

```perl6
unit class Price:ver<0.0.1>;

class X::Price::PriceInvalid is Exception {
    has $.price;

    method message() {
        return "Price $!price not valid"
    }
}

# Price is stored in cents USD
has Int $.price is required;

method price () {
    $!price / 100; # return a Rat
}

# Real is all Numeric values except Complex
multi submethod BUILD ( Real :$price ){
    $!price = Int($price * 100);
}

multi submethod BUILD ( Str :$price ){
    $price .= trans(/<-[0..9.]>/ => '');
    unless ($price ~~ m/\.\d**2$/) {
        X::Price::PriceInvalid(:$price).throw;
    }
    $!price = Int($price * 100);
}

method Str() {
    return sprintf("%.2f", ($!price/100));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to unstick this by using named parameters and overloading `BUILD`.

Answer (score 9):

The `new` methods are being declared as taking a positional parameter:

```
multi method new(Int $price) {
    say "Int constructor";
    return self.bless(:$price);
}
```

But then being called as `Price.new(price => $priceInt)`, which is passing a named argument. Therefore, since all of the `multi` candidates that wish for the extra positional argument are not applicable.

The most immediate fix is to change the constructor calls to `Price.new($priceInt)` instead.

Another option is to write the `new` methods as `multi method new(Int :$price) { ... }`, noting that the `return self.new(Int($price * 100));` would need to become `return self.new(price => Int($price * 100));` to fit with that change.

A few other assorted notes about the code that may be helpful:

- The `new` method is is normally overridden to change the *interface* to construction (such as accepting positional parameters instead of named ones), while `BUILD` and `TWEAK` are used to control how the values are mapped to attributes. If you choose to have the `new` methods take named parameters, it may also be better to handle the coercion login inside of `BUILD`.
- In Perl 6, `Num` is a floating point number, while `Rat` is a rational number (stored as integer numerator and denominator). A literal `123.4567890` is not `Num`, but rather a `Rat`. A `Num` literal always has an `e` exponent part (like `123.45e1`). However, since the problem here is dealing with currency, `Rat` is actually the correct choice, so I'd change the code to use the `Rat` type, not `Num`, and leave the literal as is.
- The `toString` method would be more naturally named `Str` in Perl 6. Types define how they coerce into other things by writing a method with that type name. Calling it `Str` will mean that it will automatically be called if a `Price` instance is interpolated in a string, or used with the `~` prefix operator.
- An exception needs to be constructed, so `die(X::Price::PriceInvalid(:$price));` should be `die(X::Price::PriceInvalid.new(:$price));`.